# How can I format the output line as either a string or object fields?

Tags: powershell

The goal is to run a script that will check PowerShell remoting to a list of hosts. I would like for the status of each job to appear on a single line rather than the host and State on separate lines. I would like to see:

```
server1 Completed
server2 Completed
server3 Failed
server4 Completed
```

I tried using `{"$_.Location, $_.State"}` as the last line, but that appears to emit the types rather than values.

Do I need to create a `New-Object` to contain these two fields to output?

Yes, it is overkill to use -AsJob on such a tiny request. The next goal is to build something that will start long running jobs.

Any suggestions about formatting the output? Or, about anything else in here that is not PowerShell-ic.

```
$server_list = @(
    'server1'
    ,'server2'
    ,'server3'
    ,'server4'
)

$outfile = ".\get-psversions.csv"

$server_list |
    ForEach-Object {
        $thishost = $_

        Try {
            $current_host = $_
            $v = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $current_host {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion} -ErrorAction Stop -AsJob
        }
        Catch
        {
            $v = New-Object -TypeName "System.Version"
            $v | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PSComputerName -Value "$thishost connect failed"
        }
        $v
    }
Get-Job | Wait-Job | ForEach-Object {$_.Location, $_.State}
```

```
PS X:\Scripts\PSAutomation> .\get-v2.ps1

Id     Name      PSJobTypeName   State     HasMoreData   Location      Command
--     ----      -------------   -----     -----------   --------      -------
390    Job390    RemoteJob       Running   True          server1       $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
392    Job392    RemoteJob       Running   True          server2       $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
394    Job394    RemoteJob       Running   True          server3       $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
396    Job396    RemoteJob       Running   True          server4       $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
server1
Completed
server2
Completed
server3
Failed
server4
Completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting properties of objects use [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Select-Object Location, State
```

Pipe the result into [`Format-Table`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) if you need to enforce tabular output (by default up to 4 properties are displayed in tabular form, if the number of displayed properties goes beyond that PowerShell switches to list form).

```
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Select-Object Location, State | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Of course you can also use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) if you need output strings with a specific format:

```
Get-Job | Wait-Job | ForEach-Object { "{0}:`t{1}" -f $_.Location, $_.State }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to a ForEach-Object like:

```
ForEach-Object {"$($_.Location) $($_.State)"}
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Kory Gill. This is much like `command substitution` in *nix shells.

Comment: @Liturgist In PowerShell it's called [subexpression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx), but essentially it's the same thing.